# how to get an string (like success message) from javascript alert box and stored in to an database using ruby watir

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

How to get an string (like success message) from javascript alert box & stored in to an database using ruby.

`begin
    require 'watir'
    require 'rubygems'
    chromedriver_path =     File.join(File.absolute_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)),"browser","chromedriver.exe")
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = chromedriver_path
    browser = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
    browser.goto "http://google.com"
    browser.goto ""//here i am opening an website.
    browser.button(:type => "button").click
    browser.text_field(:id => "auth-email").set ""//here i am setting my email.
    browser.text_field(:id, "auth-mobile").set ""//here i am setting my mobile.

    browser.button(:type => "submit").click
    browser.text_field(:id => "auth-password").set ""//here i am setting pswd.
    browser.button(:id =>"auth-login-button").click
    sleep 2
    browser.span(:id => "SiteMapPath").a(:text => "Home").click
    sleep 2
    browser.select_list(:name => 'Property').select 'Apartment / Flat'
    sleep 2
    browser.select_list(:id => 'Purpose').select 'Rent'
    sleep 2
    browser.select_list(:name => 'ddlCity').select''//select a city. 
    sleep 2
    browser.button(:id => "Requirement").click
    sleep 2
    browser.select_list(:id => 'price').option(:value => '6').select
    sleep 2
    browser.select_list(:id => 'bedrooms').select "3"
    sleep 5
    browser.button(:id =>"auth-extra-button").click
    sleep 5
    if browser.alert.exists?
    browser.alert.ok 
    end
    sleep 5
    browser.button(:id =>"Sign").click
    sleep 5
    browser.goto ""//here i am logging out.
    sleep 5
    browser.close`.
 after clicking an auth-extra-button button i am getting an alert box in that a message is displaying. i have to copy that message and store in a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the message from an alert using `Alert#text`.

For example, say you have the following button that opens an alert dialog:

```
<input id="alert" type="button" onclick="alert('ok')" value="Alert">
```

Then the following will return the message in the alert:

```
browser.alert.text
#=> "ok"
```

Comment: but my scenario is different .i will send my code can u check it once

Comment: i tried it but its not helpful for me.where i am doing wrong

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? What do you mean by your scenario is different? What do you mean by it is not working - eg is there an error, does it return an empty String?

Comment: after clicking on auth-extra-button in the above code an alert pop is displaying with a success message - Requirement '2 bedroom Apartment / Flat on rent'.and then i am going to click on ok. before that i want to store that success  message in to my database.

Comment: Are you then saying that `browser.alert.text` does not return the String "Requirement '2 bedroom Apartment / Flat on rent'"? What does it return?

Comment: i used b.alert.text before the if browser.alert.exists? browser.alert.ok  end.at that time it is not returning anything.its executing the next step and going on till to the end and finishing the process.

Comment: That's interesting. It would help if you can create a page that reproduces the problem.

Comment: sry. i am new to these.can u please elaborate what u r saying about.

Comment: Without being able to reproduce your problem, it is hard to fix it. If you create a page that exhibits the same problem (ie any related HTML, CSS and JavaScript) or the URL of the page you are testing, that would help us be able to reproduce the issue.